# How to parse nested JSON data using Javascript efficiently?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, nested

I have nested JSON data which I am trying to parse using Javascript:

```
[
    {
        "fullUrl": "https://replacedURL.org/v/r4/fhir/MedicationRequest/83b6c511-8b78-4fe2-b484-346ddee61933",
        "resource": {
            "resourceType": "MedicationRequest",
            "id": "83b6c511-8b78-4fe2-b484-346ddee61933",
            "meta": {
                "versionId": "4",
                "lastUpdated": "2021-04-06T03:14:44.834-04:00",
                "tag": [
                    {
                        "system": "https://smarthealthit.org/tags",
                        "code": "synthea-5-2019"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "status": "active",
            "intent": "order",
            "medicationCodeableConcept": {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "system": "http://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/rxnorm",
                        "code": "316049",
                        "display": "Hydrochlorothiazide 25 MG"
                    }
                ],
                "text": "Hydrochlorothiazide 25 MG"
            },
            "subject": {
                "reference": "Patient/2cda5aad-e409-4070-9a15-e1c35c46ed5a"
            },
```

How do I parse and print the names all of the medications into a div element with id="meds" under the JSON key "text"?  What  I am trying which is incomplete:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < prop.length; i++) {
        if(typeof obj[prop[i]] == 'undefined')
            return defval;
        obj = obj[prop[i]];
        document.getElementById("meds").innerText = obj ++ ;
    }
```

Not entirely sure what do to here.  Help please?

Comment: If the JSON needs parsing, you need to use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Can you provide the definitions for `obj` and `prop`? It is hard to understand what you have thusfar without more complete code.

Comment: Thanks @JohnPaulR   This is the problem - I am not sure how to start the definitions of obj and prop nor do I fully understand where to put the JSON.parse javascript.   I am not sure how to structure this or cycle through each key to print the value.

Comment: JSON.parse reads a JSON string and returns an object, generated from that JSON data. You would go through it like any js object.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to populate the DIV element with a list of medications include

1. Obtain the JSON text which encodes the data object.
2. Parse the JSON (text) to create a JavaScript Object value
3. Use the object obtained to list medications in a DIV element.

Implementing step 1 depends on the choice of communication API used on the frontend (e.g. `fetch`, `axios` or `jQuery`) or if the JSON string is hardcoded in a script element inserted into page HTML when serving the page.

Step 2 may be included in step 1 by some APIs automatically, based on the mime type of response content, or by executing some kind of `json` method on the response object. If the front end gets the JSON as a text string it can call `JSON.parse` to convert the text into an object.

Step 3 doesn't *appear* to need parsing - the `text` property is of a nested object in an array entry. Standard shortcut notation to access its value may suffice. For example:

```
// assume dataArray is the result of parsing the JSON text.
// assume "meds" is the id of a DIV element

function listMeds( dataArray) {
  const div = document.getElementById("meds");
  dataArray
  .map(entry => entry.resource.medicationCodeableConcept.text)
  .map( med=> {
     const span = document.createElement("span");
     span.textContent = med;
     const br = document.createElement("br");
     div.appendChild(span);
     div.appendChild( br);
   })
}
```